# Need a Concept to setting Local Notification with repeat interval set by user

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification, ios8.1

I am creating an app feature to my existing app that will allow pharmacy patients to enter their name which will display a list of names in a table view, then click on a name, and there is another table view where they can add medications, and then click on a medication and there is another table view where they can add reminders to take their medications delivered via Local notifications. I have everything setup except for the form where they add a reminder where they select a time, am/pm, and are able to repeat every minute, or hour, or everyday and will also have a title of this reminder. For example, it will say "Aspirin" as a title, and then below it in a subtitle "8:00AM Everyday", then the next reminder on the list in the reminder table view would show "Aspirin" and "8:00Pm everyday". This form will allow them to add a reminder for each medication they take.

I just can't figure out what classes or frameworks I should start with this. I need the Alarm feature of the repeat interval and then I need that to turn into a notification. I think I can handle the rest as far as getting the information to show up in the table. But I need a way to build this simple form. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking about the UI or about how to store the user choice and manage local notifications? How are you storing other data in the app?

Comment: I followed a tutorial on youtube that allows me to add users first name and last name in a table view, then once you click on that, then there is a table view for medications, and then another for reminders. I added the reminders table view and view controller for the form. But I don't know how to take the data from that form which would be the reminder title and the time & repeat form fields to work. I could probably get that information stored, but I don't know what to use for the notification and reminder repeat.

Comment: I am thinking that I could use some kind of variable to pass to the notification UI for the interval when each one is set. But is that possible? I am new to the app world btw. This is the last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I found this tutorial for the reminder but it uses a date picker. I need it to be a dropdown for time and am/pm and another to set the intervals. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/

Comment: You should use a date picker which only shows times, not a drop down... Interval could be buttons for each day of the week.

Comment: I see it the options now. So switch date and time to just Time. I notice on my alarm on my 5s, it has a repeat, every sunday, every monday, etc.. So what you are saying is that I would need to create another view controller with all of the days. That would work! I didn't think of it like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom class to hold your data for each reminder. Use `NSDateComponents` to store the time, and possibly the day of the week if the reminder doesn't repeat daily. Consider using a `BOOL` for if the reminder does repeat daily.

Comment: Would that work just like the alarm settings? I figured out I use the time picker and not the date and time picker. Then set another view controller to select day of week. I kind of need it to be exactly like the alarm. But instead of the alarm action, I need it to send a notification at the time specified.

Comment: This is gathering and storing the data that you will use to create your `UILocalNotification` instances that you register with the application.